# Filtering on a Azure service bus topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a main application that allows a user to edit all of their data (about 20 fields). When this is updated I add this to a Service Bus topic which I have other areas of the system subscribing to.

One of these subscriptions only cares if a single field is updated (phone number). I'm wondering what is the best way to handle this?

Looking at the GitHub example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-servicebus-messaging-samples/tree/master/TopicFilters), it states:

> The cost of choosing complex filter rules is lower overall message throughput at the subscription, topic, and namespace level, since evaluating rules costs compute time. Whenever possible, applications should choose correlation filters over SQL-like filters since they are much more efficient in processing and therefore have less impact on throughput.

So from what I can gather I could add what properties have been updated using the `properties` property on the `BrokeredMessage` class and filter based on that but that is not recommended based on the above statement.

I could let the message go through and action it (this would just update a row in a table to the same value) but this seems redundant.

Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1):

If you have predefined values you'd be filtering on for that subscription, use `CorrelationFiter`. In case it requires conditional match (e.g. a phone number that starts with area code 321), then `SqlFilter` is absolutely fine. It really depends how much of filtering you're going to perform. My suggestion would be benchmarking and measuring the performance, tweaking your filters to give you the optional result.

Comment: Is it possible to update the rules in an existing topic subscription?

Comment: Sounds like a new question to be posted ;) No, rules cannot be modified, but they can be replaced.

Comment: Obscure access to Azure Java SDK docs is making it hard to understand what is possible. I did notice that there is an `updateSubscription` method for `ServiceBusContract` that takes a `SubscriptionInfo` instance encapsulating the filters. Essentially, I am trying to replace the metadata associated with an existing subscription.